# Optimize post insert and delete for bulk operations?

Tags: posts, optimization, bulk

Not much noticeable when working with individual posts, but when you create or delete multiple thousands in bulk and by code - process is quite slow.

Are there any good tweaks to apply and corners to cut?

Context:

- `wp_insert_post()` with categories and tags passed;
- add several custom fields;
- create and associate attachments (from existing files).

Comment: It would be interesting to [profile this operation](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) so we can study the bottlenecks. Measure before you optimize!

Comment: @Jan Fabry makes sense. I will try to setup a profiled test run after I am done with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When updating post taxonomies, you can call [`wp_defer_term_counting( true )`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1975) before you do your mass operation, and then `wp_defer_term_counting( false )` to update the term counts only once per term.

Comment: Good one! I've seen this tweak mentioned, but completely forgot about it.

Comment: nice one, never heard of it. you got my +1