# wp_set_object_terms and arrays

Tags: php, functions, terms

I need to add a category to about 2500 posts, and either need to use an SQL query or `wp_set_object_terms` with PHP. I'm looking at `wp_set_object_terms` so I can add a category and not impact the currently assigned categories.

The function below that uses `wp_set_object_terms'` (from the WordPress Codex) adds one or more categories from an array (in the case of the example, categories 6 and 8) to the post with the ID of 42 (in the example).

But I need to be able to add an array of post IDs (`$object_id`), not an array of categories.

According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms, `$object_id` has to be a single integer.

How can I use an array of ~2500 post IDs for `$object_id`? Do I need to a for each loop and run through the array and process each category addition to each post ID one at a time?

From https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms :

```
// An array of IDs of categories we to add to this post. (Not using an array)
$cat_ids = array( 6, 8 );

// Add these categories, note the last argument is true.
// (42 is the $object_id; I will hardcode the category ID)
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( 42, $cat_ids, 'category', true );

if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
    // There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn't be set.
} else {
    // Success! These categories were added to the post.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I doubt it would justify the effort of writing custom SQL queries for only 2500 posts.

Within the `wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, ... )` function we have:

```
$object_id = (int) $object_id;
```

so it's correct that it only takes a single post id as input.

So you would need to loop over your `$post_ids` array but it might be sufficient to use the `wp_defer_term_counting()` trick<sup>1)</sup>:

```
/**
 * Add terms to posts (with debug display)
 */
function wpse_terms_to_posts( $terms, $taxonomy, $append, &$post_ids )
{
    wp_defer_term_counting( true );

    print '<ul>';
    foreach( (array) $post_ids as $post_id )
    {
        $tt_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append );

        print '<li>';
        if( is_wp_error( $tt_ids ) )
            printf(
                'Problem adding terms to post_id: %d - Error: %s',
                $post_id,
                $tt_ids->get_error_message()
            );
    else
            print 'Success adding terms to post_id: ' . $post_id ;
        print '</li>';
    }
    print '</ul>';

    wp_defer_term_counting( false );
}
```

Here we pass `$post_ids` by reference in case it's very large.

**Usage (PHP 5.4+) :**

```
wpse_terms_to_posts(
    $terms     = [ 6, 8 ],
    $taxonomy  = 'category',
    $append    = true,
    $post_ids  = [ 123, 234, 345 ]
);
```

We could even slice the `$post_ids` array, if 2500 is too much for our system in a single run.

Here's an example how we can run the function with `admin-ajax.php` with such a *slicing* feature:

We create our own action with:

```
/**
 * Custom wp ajax action to activate our wpse_terms_to_posts() function
 * 
 * Example: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
 *          ?action=wpse-terms-to-posts&wpse_offset=0&wpse_length=500
 */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse-terms-to-posts', function()
{
    $offset = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'wpse_offset', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $length = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'wpse_length', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    // Check for user capability and non empty user input:
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && '' !== $offset && '' !== $length  )
    {
        print '<h3>Start:</h3>';      
        $start = microtime( true );

        // Settings - Edit to your needs:
        $terms     = [ 6, 8 ];
        $taxonomy  = 'category';
        $append    = true;
        $post_ids  = [ 123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789 ];

        // Add terms to posts:
        wpse_terms_to_posts (
            $terms,
            $taxonomy,
            $append,
            array_slice( $post_ids, $offset, $length )
        );

        printf( '<h3>Done in %f seconds</h3>', microtime( true ) - $start );         
        exit();
    }

} );
```

where we use the `wpse_offset` and `wpse_length` GET parameters to slice the posts array.

If we want to slice the post ids array into chunks of 500, we can activate it manually with:

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpse-terms-to-posts&wpse_offset=0&wpse_length=500

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpse-terms-to-posts&wpse_offset=500&wpse_length=500

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpse-terms-to-posts&wpse_offset=1000&wpse_length=500

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpse-terms-to-posts&wpse_offset=1500&wpse_length=500

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpse-terms-to-posts&wpse_offset=2000&wpse_length=500
```

That way we can check for any term errors.

Hope you can modify this to your needs.

<sup>1)</sup> `wp_defer_term_counting()` was first mentioned on WPSE in this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9634/26350) by @JanFabry

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Looks to be exactly what I need. Sorry, just learning here: where does the "usage" `wpse_terms_to_posts ( $terms...` go? Inside the function? I get a parse error on it.

Comment: I assume PHP 5.4+ by using the `[]` array notation, that could be the parse error you got? I updated the answer with an example how you can activate the `wpse_terms_to_posts` function via `admin-ajax.php`. @markratledge

Comment: I love this approach. I had a foreach loop in mind, but with the huge amount of posts, the actual operation can bom out due to memory or time. :-). Your approach caters well for this issues

Comment: It's handy if we want to watch out for errors (then I usually don't print out the successful inserts ). One could also log the errors into a file instead. If the number of manual "slice" calls is too large, then I sometimes use a linux `cron` script with `curl` or `wget`. Then we need a no_priv type of action. We could also check out the upgrade process from the multisite with auto refresh from javascript, where the browser page must be open during the process.  @PieterGoosen

Comment: Very nice; let me check this out later today.

Comment: Hopefully you made some good progress on the problem ;-) @markratledge